# Software for Creating Game Sound Effects

Tags: audio, game-development

To cut a long story short, you can head over to this topic on Game Dev Stack Exchange :
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103064/how-can-a-one-man-team-create-game-audio

I am not a sound designer but I want software to make some sound effects for my game like explosions, engines' sounds, fire, ... etc.

Some on Unity forums suggested FL Studio but what I see is FL Studio is for music and isn't friendly for non-sound designers.

What about Ableton Live with Ableton Push ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What about the options you mentioned?  Did you try them?  If they don't meet your needs, why not?  We need more information to help you!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Actually ....... No But I want to know if they will meet my needs or if they won't so I asked "What (or how) about Ableton Live with Ableton Push ?"

Comment: The top answer on that question actually says *"creating sound effects is a fairly simple task as long as you have a fairly decent microphone.*". Everyday sounds edited with something like [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) should be sufficient for most game sound effects.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer on the question you referred to actually says "*creating sound effects is a fairly simple task as long as you have a fairly decent microphone.*". Everyday sounds edited with something like Audacity should be sufficient for most game sound effects.

**Credits**: [huey](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/474/huey) (in one of the comments below the question here)